# What is the difference between longblob and longtext in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, types, long-integer, sqldatatypes

What is difference between longblob and longtext in mysql?

What should I use to save a long topic ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

BLOBs are for Binary Large Objects. If you're storing binary data in your DB, then BLOB would be the table type you want. Otherwise.. longtext.

In your case longtext.

Comment: what bad about that? google is my friend and I can learn myself too doing google search and helping other people :)

Comment: There's nothing bad about it, I wanted to post exactly the same but you beat me to it with a few seconds haha! +1

Comment: Try to cite your sources, tell the user to google it in this case and maybe downvote the OP if deserved. Though +1 for this.

Answer (score 18):

BLOB and TEXT are basically identical, *except* that TEXT fields have character set translation rules applied. BLOB fields do not. So with BLOB what you put in is what you get. With TEXT, what you put may not be what you get out.

Comment: For example? You statement creates mystery.

Comment: @SahuVKumar: I'd assume that it's safe to put text data into either `BLOB` or `TEXT` types. However, my guess is that putting binary data into `BLOB` and `TEXT` types might yield different results.

Answer (score 7):

You can use collation & character sets on `TEXT` columns, which would mean that:

1. If you specify a different charset for a connection than the `TEXT` column is (for instance,`latin1` column, `utf-8` requested), MySQL will convert the contents to the required charset.
2. You can sort & compare `TEXT` columns based on collation.

`BLOB`'s are just 'binary sequences', and you'll get them 'as is'.

Comment: **convert the contents** is a good hint at something that people generally don't mention when explaining the difference between BLOB and TEXT: performance. Sometimes both might be suitable for some data so it would be wise to pick the one with the least performance penalty.

Comment: I think this is what I am experiencing, and it may help: A specific example where this occurs is a Drupal longtext field with UTF-8 Unicode specified throws PDO Exception when a higher unicode emoji ("" in this case) is inserted, but the same database with a LONGBLOG field accepts it just fine.