# Unserializing PHP array not working

Tags: php, mysql, deserialization, blob

I have the following serialized array stored in a MySQL longblob data field:

```
a:1:{s:10:"attributes";a:1:{s:13:"Ticket Holder";a:1:{i:0;s:8:"Joe Blow";}}}
```

In PHP, when I query the field, unserialize it, and print it out, the following empty array is printed:

```
Array
(
)
```

This is the table create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `order` (
  `state` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET ascii DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` longblob,
  `created` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: what code are you using to deserialize it?

Comment: What function are you using to perfom the query and unserialize?

Comment: It's in Drupal 8.  I'm using the select function in \Drupal\Core\Database\Connection for the query.  I'm simply using the PHP unserialize function to deserialize it.

Comment: tried it in phpfiddle, and `unserialize()` throws an exception. If I reproduce the array and serialize it, I get `a:1:{s:10:"attributes";a:1:{s:13:"ticket holder";a:1:{i:0;s:8:"Joe Blow";}}}` Bottom Line: I think there's a problem with the data you're getting

Comment: I changed the ticket holder name for privacy purposes. This is my serialization code serialize(['attributes' => ['Ticket Holder' => ['Joe Blow']]]).

Comment: I just noticed this in the logs 'Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 1 bytes'.

Comment: @user320691 out of curiosity, what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Version 5.6.30 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Serialization works with varchar fields but not longblob.  Unfortunately, I have to use the latter.

Comment: Part `s:13:"Joe Blow"` doesn't make any sense in that serialized array or you have some "hidden" characters inside that string.

Comment: s:13:"Joe Blow" was changed to pose this question.  The original name had 13 characters.

Comment: Since the string itself is [a valid serialization format](https://3v4l.org/bitY0), we must conclude there is non-printing data in there. Try piping the column value through `cat -vet`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use cat -vet in PHP.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555496/what-is-the-difference-between-longblob-and-longtext-in-mysql

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544749/what-column-type-should-be-used-to-store-serialized-data-in-a-mysql-db

Comment: Consider using JSON instead of serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the column to UTF8 in the SELECT statement and then unserializing it.

```
CONVERT (data USING utf8)
```

I'm not sure why this is necessary.  I'm guessing it has something to do with the utf8mb4_general_ci collation.

Thank you for all of your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

Your serialized data is invalid. You must never mainpulate serialized data manually.

Strings are serialized as:

```
s:<i>:"<s>";
```

where `<i>` is an integer representing the string length of `<s>`, and `<s>` is the string value.

So in this case valid data is :

```
a:1:{s:10:"attributes";a:1:{s:13:"Ticket Holder";a:1:{i:0;s:8:"Joe Blow";}}}
```

`Joe Blow` string length is 8 but in your serialized strings is defined 13.

See : [Structure of a Serialized PHP string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297926/structure-of-a-serialized-php-string)

Comment: From OP: "`s:13:"Joe Blow"` was changed to pose this question. The original name had 13 characters"

Comment: Please replace `Joe Blow` with another valid string in your question to prevent mistake.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Alireza.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

## Use `base64_encode`

The core problem comes from the binary encoding done by the database and the extra bytes it adds to the value stored. This "corrupts" the data that is being fetched from the database and causes `unserialize` to fail. To help mitigate this problem, you can use `base64_encode` and `base64_decode` which will allow you to insert and extract the data painlessly.

```
// data is encoded before insert
$dataToInsert = base64_encode(serialize($myArray));

// decode the data before unserializing it
$dataToRead = unserialize(base64_decode($longblob));
```

Comment: @bishop the problem comes from the encoding done by the `longblob` type, which makes the corrupts the data, which in turn causes `unserialize` to fail. Using `base64_encode` and `base64_decode` prevents this

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't store anything but a:0:{}.  When not using base64 encoding, it stores the serialized array correctly.  I just haven't been able to retrieve it from a longblob field.  Thanks William.

Comment: If the OP is inserting data into his database without properly espcaping it, then base64 encoding the serialized PHP might fix the immediate problem but this is not applicable to all the data stored in a database - and implies that the code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Merely using a longblob does not corrupt data.